# mysql security logging

Tags: databases, brute-force, logging, mysql, detection

1. Is there any logging available that logs mysql connection attempts to the port, login attempts, and times succeeded with username, IP address and date time?
   Im trying to detect brute force attempts.
2. Is there a way to setup a mysql automatic brute force delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to setup [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) (Host-Based Intrusion Detection System):

> The default mysql ruleset includes checking for:
>
> rule-id-50105
>   Database authentication success.
>
> rule-id-50106
>   Database authentication failure.
>
> rule-id-50107
>   Database query.
>
> rule-id-50108
>   User disconnected from database.
>
> rule-id-50120
>   Database shutdown messge.
>
> rule-id-50121
>   Database startup message.
>
> rule-id-50125
>   Database error.
>
> rule-id-50126
>   Database fatal error.
>
> rule-id-50180
>   Multiple database errors.
>
> http://www.ossec.net/doc/rules/rules/50_mysql_rules.xml.html

The alerts provide some of the information you want (e.g. timestamp, datetime, username).  You can also easily create your own OSSEC rules to capture more details or to create complex rules and actions.

Comment: -1,  No, if just anyone can connect to mysql then you have seriously ***ed up.   OSSEC should never come into play.

Comment: @Rook - where does he say anyone can connect?  what if this mysql instance is only internally accessible?  the internal network could be compromised or an employee could be trying to gain illicit access.  in either case, OSSEC can help him catch bad activity.

Answer (score 4):

If you have people connecting to mysql you have already seriously messed up.  You need to change your firewall settings to make sure that only trusted hosts can connect and **no one else**.

An attacker could easily summon a bot net of 1,000,000 in size to brute force your mysql server.  You need a white list approach to this problem.